# Where and when was my Schwinn Traveler made?

Tags: road

I think that I have a 1987 Schwinn Traveler.  The serial number is I626829.  The code on my head badge is 0227.  The head badge says Schwinn Chicago and there is a star in the middle.

I have read that Schwinn did not use the letter "I" in their serial numbers but I clearly have a bike that has it.  I would appreciate it if you could let me know what that means.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I thought Schwinn was contracting to Giant/Panasonic before 1987.

Comment: My guess would be Taiwan, but that's only a guess.

Comment: I understand its nice to know these things, but what really matters is that you ride it.   Like a mutt dog from the pound vs a pedigree, getting out on your bike is more important.    Its highly unlikely to be a collectible bike,   and knowing where it was conceived won't change the ride or the fit you have right now.

Answer (score 3):

The serial number is for a Japan manucatured Schwinn.  The serial number format is Bridgestone.  "I" is for the ninth month(September) and the first digit, "6" is for the year of manufacture 1986.  This matches somewhat with the headbadge date of day 022(January) and year 7(1987), which is supposed to be when the bicycle was assembled.

Schwinn must have used more than one Japanese manufacturer, including Panasonic.

Edit:  Did some more checking.  This is not a Panasonic or any Japanese manufacturer serial number.

Serial number from Schwinn Greenville, MS factory.  Manufacture date September 1986.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Arnold, Schwinn and Company, Chicago, IL](http://livinghistoryofillinois.com/pdf_files/Schwinn%20Bicycle%20History,%20Arnold,%20Schwinn%20and%20Company,%20Chicago,%20IL.pdf)

[image]

According to [Wiki on Schwinn history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinn_Bicycle_Company#Labor_troubles,_bankruptcy_and_demise):

> The company took advantage of the continued demand for mountain bikes, redesigning its product line with Schwinn-designed chrome-molybdenum alloy steel frames. Supplied by manufacturers in Asia, the new arrangement enabled Schwinn to reduce costs and stay competitive with Asian bicycle companies. In Taiwan, Schwinn was able to conclude a new production agreement with Giant Bicycles, transferring Schwinn's frame design and manufacturing expertise to Giant in the process. With this partnership, Schwinn increased their bicycle sales to 500,000 per year by 1985. Schwinn's annual sales soon neared the million mark, and the company turned a profit in the late 1980s. However, after unsuccessfully attempting to purchase a minority share in Giant Bicycles, Edward Schwinn Jr. negotiated a separate deal with the China Bicycle Co. (CBC) to produce bicycles to be sold under the Schwinn brand. In retaliation, Giant introduced its own line of Giant-branded bikes for sale to retailers carrying Schwinn bikes. Both Giant and CBC used the dies, plans, and technological expertise from Schwinn to greatly expand the market share of bicycles made under their own proprietary brands, first in Europe, and later in the United States

Based on this information your bike was made by either Giant or China Bicycle Company (CBC)